Next.js 14: 'Property 'events' does not exist on type 'AppRouterInstance''
I recently upgraded my Next.js project to version 14 and made some structural changes including switching from the pages directory to the app directory. I also updated imports from next/router to next/navigation. After these updates, I encountered a TypeScript error:
Property 'events' does not exist on type 'AppRouterInstance'.ts(2339)

"use client"
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"
import * as fbq from "@/lib/fbmeta/metaPixel"

const Providers = ({ children }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    fbq.pageview();

    const handleRouteChange = () => {
      fbq.pageview();
    };

    // Error occurs here
    router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", handleRouteChange);
    return () => {
      router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", handleRouteChange);
    };
  }, [router.events]);

  return <>{children}</>;
};


This error occurs when trying to access router.events. I'm not sure how to fix this issue or if there's a new way to handle events in Next.js 14. Does anyone know how to resolve this or what the correct approach should be with the updated Next.js version?

router.events is not available in the useRouter Hook from "next/navigation". But you can still achieve its functionality by combining useParams and useSearchParams
import { useParams, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation"

const Providers = ({ children }) => {
  const pathname = usePathname()
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()

  useEffect(() => {
    // this function will be executed (on routeChangeComplete)
    // 1. At the first render
    // 2. whenever the pathname or searchParams change
    fbq.pageview();    
  }, [pathname, searchParams]);

  return <>{children}</>;
};

Now, make sure to wrap the <Providers /> component by a <Suspense /> because it reads search params
You can extract that to a reusable component:
import { useParams, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation"

const useRouterEvents = (callback) => {
  const pathname = usePathname()
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()

  useEffect(() => {
    callback() 
  }, [pathname, searchParams, callback]);
};

